# Using third-party code that contains ReentrantReadWriteLock in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, reentrantreadwritelock

I'm using a third-party library that uses ReentrantReadWriteLock internally for synchronization. Of course, the library has no suspending function. For my project I'm using coroutines. Is it safe to use the library with coroutines suspending functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe just make sure to wrap the code in `runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) { }`.